# How to correctly iterate over a pandas column considering a slice of values on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, debugging

I happen to have the following information stored in a variable called `df_trading_pair`:

```
           Start Date  Open Price  High Price   Low Price  Close Price         Volume                End Date
0 2022-08-08 07:15:00  0.00001241  0.00001242  0.00001238   0.00001239  16808259334.0 2022-08-08 07:19:59.999
1 2022-08-08 07:20:00  0.00001238  0.00001239  0.00001235   0.00001238   7237826684.0 2022-08-08 07:24:59.999
2 2022-08-08 07:25:00  0.00001238  0.00001239  0.00001237   0.00001238   1768234135.0 2022-08-08 07:29:59.999
3 2022-08-08 07:30:00  0.00001238  0.00001239  0.00001236   0.00001236   5243964161.0 2022-08-08 07:34:59.999
4 2022-08-08 07:35:00  0.00001236  0.00001237  0.00001235   0.00001235   8802029320.0 2022-08-08 07:39:59.999
5 2022-08-08 07:40:00  0.00001234  0.00001236  0.00001233   0.00001234   3038529151.0 2022-08-08 07:44:59.999
6 2022-08-08 07:45:00  0.00001233  0.00001236  0.00001232   0.00001235   7700037899.0 2022-08-08 07:49:59.999
7 2022-08-08 07:50:00  0.00001235  0.00001237  0.00001235   0.00001237   1929229917.0 2022-08-08 07:54:59.999
```

I am interested in iterating over the `Open Price` column using a range of 4 values, in such a way that it prints the following information on each iteration:

#### Iteration #1

```
0    0.00001241
1    0.00001238
2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

#### Iteration #2

```
1    0.00001238
2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
4    0.00001236
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

.
.
.

#### Iteration #5

```
4    0.00001236
5    0.00001234
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

As such, I already have part of the solution and it is as follows:

```
for i in range(0, len(df_trading_pair)):
    slc = df_trading_pair["Open Price"].iloc[i : i + 4]
    print(slc)
    i = i + 1
    print("")
```

**However**, there is a problem and that is that my solution ***iterates 3 more times***, printing the following after the 5th iteration:

#### Iteration #6

```
5    0.00001234
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

#### Iteration #7

```
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

#### Iteration #8

```
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

I would like to know How can I fix it? and if possible, an explanation of why my solution did not work as expected?

Comment: remove `i=i+1`, `for` loop already increaes `i` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another sollution, using `.rolling`:

```py
for d in df["Open Price"].rolling(4):
    if len(d) != 4:
        continue
    print(d, "\n")
```

Prints:

```
0    0.00001241
1    0.00001238
2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
Name: Open Price, dtype: object 

1    0.00001238
2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
4    0.00001236
Name: Open Price, dtype: object 

2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
4    0.00001236
5    0.00001234
Name: Open Price, dtype: object 

3    0.00001238
4    0.00001236
5    0.00001234
6    0.00001233
Name: Open Price, dtype: object 

4    0.00001236
5    0.00001234
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: object
```

Comment: Interesting, may you please explain why the statement `if len(d) != 4: continue`
 makes it work as expected?

Comment: @NoahVerner The `.rolling` method starts with 1 row, then 2 rows, 3... so to filter Series with less than 4 rows I use this condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a condition on the length of the resulting Series:

```
for i in range(0, len(df_trading_pair)):
    slc = df_trading_pair["Open Price"].iloc[i : i + 4]
    if len(slc) == 4:
        print(f'Iteration #{i+1}, len: {len(slc)}')
        print(slc)
        print("")
        i = i + 1
    else:
        break
```